# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

Where I am missing info? I need to deserialize the following JSON string.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "FirstName": "Test",
      "LastName": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

For this, I have defined my LoadData Action  Method:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadData()
{
    string apiUrl = "URL";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var input = new { depot = "DATA", fromDate = "2020-06-06", toDate = "2020-06-06" };
        var response1 = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("DATAOne", input);
      
        if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PartOne>>(data);
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

For this, I have defined my class:

```cs
public class PartOne
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

But when I try using the de-serializer, it gives an exception.

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InfluxDB.Serie]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'results', line 2, position 12."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

---

1st Option, you are missing a wrapper object for `data`

```cs
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then use:

```cs
var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper<List<PartOne>>>(json).Data;
```

---

2nd Option, deserialize it first as JObject and access to data and then deserialize it to the `List<PartOne>`:

```cs
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
var jArr = jObj.GetValue("data");
var table = jArr.ToObject<List<PartOne>>();
```

Comment: @PradeepVaishya I added a 2nd option to solve this. Whatever matches you usecase better. The second one explans better what was missing (But the first one produces cleaner code I think)

Comment: I have used first one because it's much cleaner code.